# WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) How do I fix this and what does it mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

[image: Error]

I keep getting this error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

How do I fix this and what does it mean?

I have `anaconda` and Python installed. I use Jupyter Notebook and Python in VS Code.

This is in Git Bash command line.

My operating system is Windows 10 Home.

I have Python 3.9.2 and `pip` 21.1.1.

Answer (score 133):

So apparently some folder/package named -ip + some numbers was installed at `c:\python39\lib\site-packages`.

Once I checked my site packages at the link it provided and removed the `ip(random numbers)` package it stopped giving me errors.

Comment: If it has the wrong name, it probably begins with `~`

Comment: It occur when I ran pip upgrade failed, remove it should work

Comment: Yes, just go to `lib\site-packages` folder, then looking for folders start with `~` and mentioned in that warning, then remove them.

Comment: @GeorgeOgden how does a file/folder get the `~` at the start to begin with? I had just one folder with that in my Python directory.

Comment: It was just a matter of removing files in `c:\python310\lib\site-packages` that started with a `~`.

Comment: platformIO created a load of these for me, but I don't know if any of my fiddling may have caused such madness...

Comment: removing folder starting with `~` in the mentioned path is also worked for me