# Every time I run `pip` to install any package, it shows me warnings

Tags: python, windows, pip, warnings, command-prompt

I get these warnings immediately after the `pip` is run and when `pip` has finished executing:

[image: Warnings]

Here it is as text:

```
C:\Users\Raj Panpaliya> pip install pygame

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mi (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mi (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)

Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.9.6)

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mi (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mi (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mi (c:\users\raj panpaliya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)

C:\Users\Raj Panpaliya>
```

Comment: Which version of python are you running?

Comment: Could you post your Python version please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67442661/10237506

Answer (score 4):

When `pip` is removing a package, it first renames the first letter with a `-`. For example, `opencv-python` becomes `-pencv-python`. If an unistall fails, the renamed directory keeps there, but it is invalid.

You may have to remove those folders manually, to supress the warnings.