# Problem to install django proyect in IIS server windows 2016

Tags: django, iis, web-deployment, windows-server-2016

I need help with the following problem:

```
raise RuntimeError('No Apache installation can be found. Set the '
      RuntimeError: No Apache installation can be found. Set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment to its location.
```

This appears the moment I try to run the server the file. This is the content of the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Proyectoqr" 
        path="*" 
        verb="*" 
        modules="FastCgiModule" 
        scriptProcessor="C:\Python35\python.exe|C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
        resourceType="Unspecified"
        requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
     </system.webServer>

    <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\proyectoqr"/>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="proyectoqr.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="proyectoqr.settings"/>
    <add key="APPLICATION" value="get_wsgi_application()"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is the settings file of the project

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from telnetlib import LOGOUT
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.100.10.133', 'localhost', "127.0.0.1:8000", '127.0.0.1' ]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'import_export',

    "apps.equipo",
    "apps.usuariof",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'proyectoqr.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'proyectoqr.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-mx'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = ''

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

This is the configuration in handler mappings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQAkp.png)

This is the configuration in FastCGI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQAkp.png)

If you need to know another configuration please comment

error when trying to install mod_wsgi by terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQAkp.png)

New error at try to install mod_wsgi by terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X272Y.png)

Comment: I would like to ask if you are trying to install mod_wsgi in Windows?

Comment: y tried to install it

Comment: i am using default sqlite3 database in my project. But it marks an error

Comment: It seems that the problem needs to be explored step by step, you can refer to this link to try to solve this error when installing mod_wsgi : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442661/warning-ignoring-invalid-distribution-ip-c-python39-lib-site-packages-how-d

Comment: Thank you JennyDai for the help but I made another capture of the most recent error when trying to install mod_wsgi

Comment: I was able to solve the problem and the website is already on the IIS server but it doesn't recognize django static files.
PD: Thanks for the help.